# How to export Form Library Repeating table data into Excel in Infopath Form 2013

Tags: infopath-form

We have got a requirement to analyse the forms library data in Excel. We have web browser form with repeating table rows, and how we can export all forms repeating table data in a form library to excel in Infopath form 2013.

Kindly provide your insights on the requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, would you require to export the data on the InfoPath form to an Excel file when the form is submitted? Also, are you able to use custom C# code on the submit action?

Comment: Hi, the Infopath form has  2 repeating fields of check boxes (issue, acknowledge) along with some other repeating fields (issuing from one end then end user need to acknowledge), we need the report of all forms which have submitted to form library whenever we require the report (status of issued and acknowledgement need to capture on all forms whenever we require).

Answer (score 0):

Infopath form is effectively an xml file. If you write custom code in C# or Powershell you can just parse the nodes as you need to.

Comment: kindly provide the code snippet where to start the requirement using programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this should give a good start https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf868241-51c9-4261-a839-08270b70aa09/powershell-parsing-xml-amp-output-to-excel?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: In my requirement, the forms are submitted to SharePoint library and the forms are having repeating table rows & columns. I would like to get the all info which available in repeating table in all Infopath forms.